# open the camera app while iphone in lock mode programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process, lockscreen

I'm looking for solution that will enable my app to get an event from the server while the phone is in lock mode, when the event occurs the app will open the camera and take a picture.
while the phone remains locked and send the picture to the server in the back ground.

- is it possible?
- will apple store allow this kind of application?

**Clarification:**: the idea is not to take a picture without the user knowledge, the goal is to have him take a quick picture without having to open the phone & the application in order for that picture to be taken. If there is a solution that allows me to add a button like the camera build in next to the lock that's a great solution too.

Comment: mate you cannot do this. Apple will never let you do such things as spy app (no offence), if you will do it somehow then apple store will reject this.

Answer (score 1):

Short answers

- No,
- No.

This is a huge violation of privacy, and has a great potential for abuse, therefore, there is no way to sneak pictures away from the user's device on demand.

You could send a push notification and ask a user to take a photo and upload it to your server on the other hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see if my clarification edit to my question changes something in your answer, Thanks again.

Comment: I understand this might not be your intention, but it still opens the ability for abuse, that's why it is not possible. Adding a button to the lockscreen is not possible either, but you could have a push notification which would, on tap, open your application, open the camera and allow the user to take a pic and then upload it.